# How can I configure a concurrent cloud pub/sub queue when triggering cloud functions using cloud pub/sub?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am triggering cloud functions using cloud pubsub. However, I want cloud pubsub to run concurrently as many processes as I specify. Is there a way to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cloud function (instance) invocation happens automatically when triggered by a message in a pubsub topic. Those invocations are independent from each other.

The maximum number of simultaneously running cloud functions is limited by the [max-instances](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--max-instances) argument when your cloud function is deployed.

Answer (score 3):

You can't say to PubSub to deliver at a specify concurrency. When you use Push Subscription (and it's the case with Cloud Functions, you can verify that in your PubSub subscription page), the slow-start algorithm is used; and it is very well explained [here](https://youtu.be/k8lBOV-nRXI?t=160)

Therefore, more reliable and efficient are your function, higher will be the possible concurrency, but not from the beginning, it requires "warm up" of the connexion to scale at a higher rate.